# Select text in Textview without SpannableString styling

Tags: android

I'm using SpannableString to find out when a user clicks any word in a TextView (`textIsSelectable = true`). But, instead of changing the background color of the clicked word, I want it to be selected using the OS selector (with the handles).

So If I **click** (not long press) on Tuesday the following should happen:

[image]

The default behavior for the selector to appear is that the user must long press on the word. TextView doesn't have `.setSelection()` like EditText.

Comment: add android:textIsSelectable="true" and try

Comment: `textIsSelectable` is set to `true`. But the default behavior is that user has to long press to start text selection.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the problem correctly then i think it can be achievable by `performLongClick()` with `android:textIsSelectable="true"`.

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.performLongClick();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This actually selects the word, but doesn't bring up the context menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7jAq.png. When clicked again, then the menu appears as expected. Something like  `textView.performLongClickRelease()` would be ideal, but that doesn't exist of course.

Comment: Also, with the above code, the first click selects the word, but the second click doesn't fire a click event, just shows the context menu. I'm not sure why?

Comment: second click will not fire cause we have just override it with long click . For this purpose you need to Customize it a little bit make decision when to call long click and when to call Click .

Comment: Your code works to initiate the long press, and it does select the text. However the context menu is not shown till the long press is "released". Any ideas on if this is achievable?

Comment: Well i have tested it and its showing the context menu at my end . Tested on Android-21 . i did not any Spannable text on text view .

Comment: Just tried with normal text on API 22 and it works! It doesn't work on API 27, 28 though.

Comment: Okay I'll look into this once i have some free time . Can you Please add the complete requirement with question step wise . Cause i am not sure if i understood the agenda here .

Comment: Thanks! Well, what you were able to reproduce in API-21 that's the EXACT expected behavior. But it's not working on 27,28 devices. When a word is clicked (not long press), that is to be selected and the context menu (copy/paste etc) shown.